# Overflow-x and block elements

Tags: html, slider, block, inline

I'd like to have a div with other divs inside; this div,reached the maximum width of the page, should show a scrollbar. I've already realized something like that with inline elements (like `<img>` or `<span>`, but now I'm not sure of how to obtain the same with block elements.

With inline elements I used to do:

```
<div class="slider">
  <img src="image.png" />
  <img src="image.png" />
  <img src="image.png" />
  <img src="image.png" />
  <img src="image.png" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.slider{
  overflow-x: scroll;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 100%;
}
```

If I do the same with block elements, like this:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="content"></div>
  <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```

The content doesn't slides, but creates a new line and continue in the page vertically. Any suggestions?

CSS:

```
.content{
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
}
```

EDIT: the structure is more like:

```
<div class="slider">
  <div class="content">
     <div class="content2"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">
     <div class="content2"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I omitted it caus I thought it wasn't important, but probably I was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add style `display:inline-block;` to child(inner) div elements.

```
.slider>div{display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: I've already tried, doesn't work. Maybe it depends on the fact that my divs contains other block elements?

Comment: try `float:left;`. Whatever the elements if you put `display:inline-block` or `float:left` they will place in horizontal

Comment: Ok, I just checked my HTML structure (it was a little bit complicated) and figured out what was the problem, set inline-block to the right elements and now everything works greatly! Thanks